# Javascript server-render libraries with non-JS REST APIs

Tags: javascript, rest, nuxt.js, next.js, server-rendering

Are server-rendered frameworks/libraries (such as [Nextjs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) for React, [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) for Vue) and **non-JS REST API backends** (i.e. Java, Django, Go etc.) mutually exclusive or can they be used alongside?

Specifically, I am using Go for building a REST API at the backend and I wonder if I have to give it up for having the pages server-rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two different concerns, really: Vue and React are JavaScript frameworks.  They wouldn't run on your Go-based server application.

There's nothing to stop you from rendering HTML in a Go application, but a Go server is not going to run a JavaScript framework.  If it did, it would likely require extra scaffolding, and at that point you might as well set up a NodeJS server to handle rendering those routes.

Comment: So, I can use nextjs or nuxt (I do not mean the complete server-rendered concept but those JS frameworks), 'only if' I use a Javasript backend. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: That is correct.  There is probably some crazy hack that would allow you to run JS on a Go server (like this: https://github.com/dop251/goja_nodejs), but you should run a JS framework on a JS server.  You can still have a client-side React or Vue app with some of your HTML rendered on your Go server, but that's different than running the framework itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's encouraged to [use a separate API server with next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/281#issuecomment-261909799) even if you're using JavaScript for both. It's common to have the api on api.example.com, and to have the next.js app talk to it whether it's doing server-side or browser rendering.

If you want to have them on the same domain so you can cookies directly, you can use [path aliases](https://zeit.co/docs/features/path-aliases) in now.sh, a Heroku-like PaaS from Zeit, the developers of Next.js. These can be set up in development with [now-server](https://github.com/markmarijnissen/now-server). This can also be done with reverse proxies in nginx, apache, netlify, and CloudFront, or using path-based routing in AWS's Application Load Balancer.